# How to figure out slow requests in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a user that complains about slow requests. I find their session in a logging tool that we have and see that they have 8 slow consecutive requests that take 15 sec to complete (screenshot 1 + 2)

[image]

[image]

**The requests were started at 14:28:27 and completed at 14:28:42 (15 seconds)**

Below is one of the requests entry in my nginx access log

```
{
    "msec": "1638887322.982",
    "connection": "69637915",
    "connection_requests": "27",
    "pid": "29020",
    "request_id": "a5b930a025d3bb127bb3ae046966f658",
    "request_length": "5358",
    "remote_addr": "redacted",
    "remote_user": "",
    "remote_port": "redacted",
    "time_local": "07/Dec/2021:14:28:42 +0000",
    "time_iso8601": "2021-12-07T14:28:42+00:00",
    "request": "GET redacted HTTP/1.1",
    "request_uri": "redacted",
    "args": "",
    "status": "200",
    "body_bytes_sent": "316",
    "bytes_sent": "607",
    "http_referer": "redacted",
    "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36",
    "http_x_forwarded_for": "",
    "http_host": "redacted",
    "server_name": "redacted",
    "request_time": "0.145",
    "upstream": "redacted",
    "upstream_connect_time": "0.004",
    "upstream_header_time": "0.148",
    "upstream_response_time": "0.148",
    "upstream_response_length": "316",
    "upstream_cache_status": "",
    "ssl_protocol": "redacted",
    "ssl_cipher": "redacted",
    "scheme": "https",
    "request_method": "GET",
    "server_protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "pipe": ".",
    "gzip_ratio": ""
}
```

The flow of the request is the following:

```
JS Client -> requests nginx server at /api/* -> nginx proxies request to API server
```

My goal here is to find out where the request is being held up. This brings to my questions:

1. How do I figure out if the start of the request ever reached nginx? In the log there is the field `request_time` but it shows 0.145 seconds. Does that mean that the 14 secs before the request was hanging somewhere between the client and nginx itself?
2. What is some good steps for me to debug this? Properties to add to the log? Things to check?

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I figure out if the start of the request ever reached nginx? In the log there is the field request_time but it shows 0.145 seconds. Does that mean that the 14 secs before the request was hanging somewhere between the client and nginx itself?

Yes, it is the duration between the first byte nginx received and the last byte nginx sent.

> What is some good steps for me to debug this? Properties to add to the log? Things to check?

Most modern browsers have such a tool to show the timing spent by a request.

(F12 > Network > Timings)

[image: Chrome request timing]

Comment: (1) Okay, but how do I figure out what was the bottleneck then? Is there anything on my end that could cause delay before first nginx byte received?

(2) As this happened on one of my users session I am not able to check in dev tools. I have to result to logs

Comment: It looks like logs on the server side won't work because it takes only 0.145 seconds. Can you take logs on the client? Usually this is caused by low network speed.